# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Getting "Uncaught type error cannot call method 'initCollection' of undefined"

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I'm working with Worklight to build an application which uses a local storage. I declared a function `createCollection()` in common/js/myApp.js.

However when I run it on the browser simulator, the console JavaScript shows:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'initCollection' of undefined.

Any suggestions?

**My JavaScript:**

```
function wlCommonInit(){
// Common initialization code goes here
}

// inizializzazione json
window.onload = createCollection;

var isOpen = true;
var menuboxw = $("#menubox").css("width");
$("#contentbox").css("left",menuboxw);
var headerh = $("#header").height();
$("#contentbox").css("top", headerh);
$("#menu_btn").click(function(){menu()});

// apertura/chiusura menu principale
function menu() {
if(isOpen){
    $('#contentbox').animate({ left: -5 }, 1);
    $("#menubox").css("visibility", "hidden");
    isOpen = false;
}
else{
    $('#contentbox').animate({ left: menuboxw }, 1);
    $("#menubox").css("visibility", "visible");
    isOpen = true;
}
}

// creazione collection 'canti' e 'categorie'
function createCollection(){

WL.Logger.debug("Called createCollection");
WL.SimpleDialog.show("Message", "createCollection called", [{text: "Ok"}]);

var collectionCanti = "canti";
var searchFieldsCanti = {titolo: "string", autore: "string", id_categoria: "string", testo: "string"};
var collectionCategorie = "categorie";
var searchFieldsCategorie = {titolo: "string", attiva: "number"};

var success = function(data){
            logMessage("Collection created successfully " + data);
};

var failure = function(data){
            logMessage("Collection doesn't created " + data);
};

var options = {onSuccess: success, onFailure: failure};

canti = WL.JSONStore.initCollection(collectionCanti, searchFieldsCanti, options);
categorie = WL.JSONStore.initCollection(collectionCategorie, searchFieldsCategorie, options);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

1. Remove `window.onload = createCollection;`
2. Add `createCollection();` inside `wlCommonInit()`

BTW, that `logMessage` produces errors. Should probably be changed to `WL.Logger.debug` (which you are already utilizing in the code...).

---

Please go over the [IBM Worklight Getting Started training material](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/library/). No skipping.

Comment: it seems to work now, the console does not show the errors anymore but the dialog still not working. JSONStore works on iOS and Android environment only, in browser i cannot show if it works, right? I have another question: when the `wlCommonInit()` is called? What part of code must i place in it?

Comment: As I wrote, DELETE "window.onload = createCollection;", and PASTE into the wlCommonInit() function "createCollection();". I can see a dialog. wlCommonInit() is upon when the app is ready. Please read the IBM Worklight Getting Started training material.